# How to get the id value from an EclipseLink ClassDescriptor?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

We currently have the following, working soft delete customizer in place:

```java
public class SoftDeleteCustomizer implements DescriptorCustomizer {

  @Override
  public void customize(ClassDescriptor descriptor) {
    descriptor.getQueryManager().setDeleteSQLString(
        String.format("UPDATE %s SET record_status = 'D', record_status_time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id = #ID",
                      descriptor.getTableName()
        )
    );
  }

}
```

We now want to add the user that deleted the record. I could sanitize the username, but I would prefer to use a parameter / argument.

I rewrote the customizer and did not set an argument for the `#ID`, as it was already injected correctly somewhere. I then found out that it was not injected when you are using a `DeleteObjectQuery` (with arguments?). So I have to add an argument for the `#ID` it seems, but I don't know how to get the id / primary key value of the record / entity to be deleted from a `ClassDescriptor`.

This is what I have so far:

```java
  @Override
  public void customize(final ClassDescriptor descriptor) {
    final DeleteObjectQuery query = new DeleteObjectQuery();
    query.addArgument("DELETED_BY", String.class);
    query.addArgument("ID", Long.class);
    query.addArgumentValue(SecurityUtils.getUsername());
    query.addArgumentValue(...); // How to get the ID of the record to delete?
    query.setSQLString(String.format(DELETE_SQL, descriptor.getTableName()));
    descriptor.getQueryManager().setDeleteQuery(query);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, as a workaround I used our audit listener which we added as one of the `EntityListeners`. It implements `SessionCustomizer`. There I was able to do:

```java
  @Override
  public void postDelete(final DescriptorEvent event) {
    final Long id = ((AbstractEntity) event.getObject()).getId();
    // Create and execute update query to set the username
  }
```